# I am getting Crash on This for ios 9 however I had a version check already...Please suggest

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, mpmedialibrary

I am getting the crash for `iOS9` According to `Crashlytics` however I 
    had put already a version check.  Here is the Code I am using  :

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] > 9.0){

   [MPMediaLibrary requestAuthorization:^(MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus 
 authorizationStatus)
  {
     if ( authorizationStatus == MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatusAuthorized 
  )
     {

     }
     else
     {


     }
 }];
}
```

Comment: What does that crash says??

Comment: Crash Log : +[MPMediaLibrary requestAuthorization:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1a1e33cb0

Comment: For that method the minimum version is iOS 9.3

Comment: what is your device os version?

Answer (score 1):

Your app are crashing because the method `requestAuthorization:` requires iOS 9.3 at least, according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmedialibrary/1621276-requestauthorization?language=objc). Tip: for a better version check inside the `if` you should use this:

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:(NSOperatingSystemVersion){9,3,0}]
```